# How to test the behaviour of an akka actor, if it reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`?

Tags: scala, akka, stdout, scalatest, testkit

I'm writing a [UCI](https://www.chessprogramming.org/UCI) interpreter, as an Akka Finite State Machine. As per the specification, the interpreter must write its output to `stdout`, and take its input from `stdin`.

I have a test suit for the actor, and I can test some aspects (message related) of its behaviour, but I don't know how to capture the `stdout` to make assertions, nor how to send it its input through `stdin`. I've explored the scalatest API to the best of my abilities, but can't find how to achieve what I need.

This is the current test class:

```scala
package org.chess

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, TestProbe}
import org.chess.Keyword.Quit
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Matchers}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

class UCIInterpreterSpec(_system: ActorSystem)
  extends TestKit(_system)
    with Matchers
    with AnyWordSpecLike
    with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("UCIInterpreterSpec"))

  override def afterAll: Unit = {
    super.afterAll()
    shutdown(system)
  }

  "A UCI interpreter" should {

    "be able to quit" in {
      val testProbe = TestProbe()
      val interpreter = system.actorOf(UCIInterpreter.props)
      testProbe watch interpreter
      interpreter ! Command(Quit, Nil)
      testProbe.expectTerminated(interpreter, 3 seconds)
    }

  }

}
```

Of course, knowing that the interpreter can quit is useful... but not very useful. I need to test, for example, if sending the string `isready` to the interpreter, it returns `readyok`.

Is it possible that I am overcomplicating the test by using akka.testkit, instead of a simpler framework? I would like to keep using a single testing framework for simplicity, and I will need to test many other actor-related elements of the system, so if this could be solved without leaving the akka-testkit/scalatest domain, it would be fantastic.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good luck with UCI, opensource this stuff if it works ;)

Comment: Thank you! It's available at https://github.com/bruno-unna/chess (currently working on the `uci-implementation` branch). I haven't defined the licence yet, but of course it will be open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the design of your Actor.

The Actor should not read `stdin` or write `stdout` directly. Instead, give the actor objects in the `Props` that provide input and accept output. `stdin` could be something like `() => String` that is called each time input is needed. `stdout` could be `String => Unit` that is called each time output is generated. Or you could use `Streams` or similar constructs that are designed to be abstract sources and sinks of data.

In production code you pass objects that use `stdin` and `stdout`, but for test code you pass objects that read and write memory buffers. You can then check that the appropriate input is consumed by the Actor and that the appropriate output is generated by the Actor.

Comment: Completely agree with this answer with regards to using inversion of control to achieve that. I.e. pass something abstract that can be read from instead of hardcoding `stdin` dependency. In some cases when you don't have that control, like if you are testing a library, you might want to reassign `stdin`/`stdout` with methods like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream) `System.setIn(...InputStream...)`.

Comment: Perhaps more robust reassigning approach would be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523167/1972909.